# Calculating data from one DB table with range of dates

Tags: php, sql, joomla3.0

I have sql function:

```
        $sql = "SELECT date(datum_ura) as datetime, 
                   COUNT(CASE rezultat_status_fk WHEN 5 THEN rezultat_status_fk END) AS half_lost, AVG(kvota) as average, SUM(vlozek) as vlozek,
                   SUM(CASE rezultat_status_fk WHEN 1 THEN vlozek * kvota WHEN 2 THEN vlozek WHEN 3 THEN 0 END) AS case_profit,
                   SUM(CASE rezultat_status_fk WHEN 1 THEN vlozek * kvota-vlozek WHEN 2 THEN 0 WHEN 3 THEN -vlozek END) AS profit
            FROM bs_analiza 
            WHERE users_fk=$user_id"." group by date(datum_ura)";
```

The function is getting data from one table and calculates it and show results by dates. I'm trying to do a function which can sum current date result with the day before result....and so on.

I'm thinking of something like:

```
foreach ($items as $key => $value) {    
$date = $value->datetime;           
    $prev_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date .' -1 day'));
    $prev_date = strtotime($prev_date);
    $i = $key-1;
$profit_before = $items[$i]->$prev_date;
```

But I'm still getting the same results.

Comment: Do you mean a cumulative sum or something like a sliding window with a range of 2 days? Btw it helps to add the DBMS.

Comment: Cumulative sum is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with selects from your intermediate result, I suggest you either create a view or use `WITH`.

```
SELECT
   datetime,
   (SELECT SUM(vlozek) FROM ... WHERE datetime >= t.datetime) vlozek_cumsum,
   (SELECT SUM(case_profit) FROM ... WHERE datetime >= t.datetime) case_profit_cumsum,
   (SELECT SUM(profit) FROM ... WHERE datetime >= t.datetime) profit_cumsum
FROM
   ... t
ORDER BY
   datetime DESC
```

`...` is your intermediate result.

Edit (to clarify): You get your intermediate result by a select statement. So you can either

1. Create a view and replace `...` by the name of the view or

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW <view_name> AS <select_stmt>
   ```
2. Use `WITH` and replace all `...` in the query above by the alias name.

   ```
   WITH <alias_name> AS ( <select_stmt> )
   SELECT
      ...
   ```

Comment: I'm not quite sute how to achive that as sql is not my passion. Is it possible to explain little bit more. Thanks

Comment: @kgg.becks added more details.